# How to make the GUI elements of windows version Neovim appear?

Tags: user-interface, vim, neovim

My Neovim on windows 10 installed using chocolatey method guided by the [website of Neovim](https://github.com/neovim/neovim/wiki/Installing-Neovim#windows), does not have any GUI element (including tab, menu, or toolbar) after I run nvim-qt.exe. Can any one help me? Now, both the _vimrc and all the Vunle Plugin of my gVim are loaded succeed into my Neovim environment. The screen looks like this,
[cool_neovim_screen_but_without_gui_element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iXKtS.png)

Answer (score 0):

You should look up the gui settings options

```
:h guioptions
```

In vim/nvim.

I do:

```
set guioptions=egmrti
```

In my nvim startup file to remove menu, scrollbars, and a few other things. Against look at the documentation to see what each of those letters set/unset.

Comment: I have used default option, i.e., guioptions=egmrLtT, but failed to make the GUI elements of windows version Neovim appear. Can you use menu, scrollbars and a few other things of windows version neovim?